# Open a webpage as soon as Webbrowser1 changes page?

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, html

I'm starting out coding and I've encountered a problem in the VB.NET application I'm creating.

When a new webpage is loaded in `Webbrowser1` I want my code to open a link to execute in your own webbrowser, i.e chrome, Firefox.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is not a beginners task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim FirstRun As Boolean = True
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com")
    End Sub
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        If Not FirstRun Then Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com")
        FirstRun = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help :) Now the question is how I would go about making this happen just once after a button has ben pressed. Sorry for being dumb.

Comment: just put **Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com")** under Button_Click event. :)

Comment: Yeah that I know, I meant how would I make it execute ' Process.Start("stackoverflow.com") ' after that webbrowser1 webpage has changed after clicking the button? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok. Let me make it clear. After a Webbrowser1 is loaded, you will click Button1 then the Process.Start will execute?

Comment: Let me clear this up a bit :P... I have a webbrowser, when I click the first button it will change to another page. When the second page is loaded I want Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com") to happen.

Comment: Ty. Now the problem is that it automatically opens the page as soon as I start the app because the first webpage loads. I only want it to use the documentcompleted code after I have pressed a button. :P